# My ID's are all the same using a foreach and @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm struggling with my MVC 5 app. I'm trying to create a form, based upon my Model.

The Model is fairly simple and for this, I've totally reduced it to bare

Survey.cs has only 1 property

```
public Dictionary<Answer, AnswerTemplate> QuestionAndAnswerTemplates { get; set; }
```

Answer.cs has only 1 property

```
public string AnswerValue {get;set;}
```

AnswerTemplate.cs has 2 properties

```
    public string ConstraintsCsv { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ConstraintsFroDropDownList
    {
        get
        {
            var result = new List<SelectListItem>();
            var split = ConstraintsCsv?.Split(',');
            foreach (var s in split)
            {
                result.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = s });
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

And finally the CSHTML (view)

```
@model Survey

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    foreach (var item in Model.QuestionAndAnswerTemplates)
    {
        @Html.DisplayFor(a => item.Key.Question)<br />
        @Html.DropDownListFor(a => item.Key.AnswerValue, item.Value.ConstraintsFroDropDownList)
        <br /><br />
    }

    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

The `Dictionary` is populated with 2 items, and as such, I see 2 `DropDownLists` on the rendered HTML in the browser. Great!

The problem is, when I inspect the source code of the rendered HTML, I get the following

```
<select id="item_Key_AnswerValue" name="item.Key.AnswerValue">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>        <br /><br />
<select id="item_Key_AnswerValue" name="item.Key.AnswerValue">
<option>Yes</option>
<option>No</option>
</select>        <br /><br />
```

As you can see, each `ID` is the same, as is the `name`
Why is this? I'd like to be able to click the Save button and have a fully populated model.

The controller is

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Survey(Survey model)
 {
     return View();//need to do something here
 }
```

But, `model` is always unpopulated (empty values).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When editing a collection of item in your razor view don't use `foreach` but a simple `for` loop.

So instead of:

```
foreach (var item in Model.QuestionAndAnswerTemplates)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(a => item.Key.Question)<br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => item.Key.AnswerValue, item.Value.ConstraintsFroDropDownList)
    <br /><br />
}
```

Use this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < Model.QuestionAndAnswerTemplates.Count(); i++)
{
    @Html.DisplayFor(a => Model.QuestionAndAnswerTemplates[i].Key.Question)<br />
    @Html.DropDownListFor(a => Model.QuestionAndAnswerTemplates[i].Key.AnswerValue, item.Value.ConstraintsFroDropDownList)
    <br /><br />
}
```

Doing it like above then `name` attribute of each of your `select` element will be bind to the position of your template in `Model.QuestionAndAnswerTemplates`.

Comment: Would it work if I used `.ElementAt(i)` instead of `[i]` ?

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions it will not work if you do that. The helper expects a property not a method call.